# Graphql get direct requested model

Tags: android, api, kotlin, graphql, retrofit

I implemented a sample of Graphql by Retrofit. I have a response like this:

```
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.e("response", response.body().toString())
```

Also, this is my interface class:

```
suspend fun postDynamicQuery(@Body body: String): Response<String>
```

Now I want to change my method by giving a direct model. this is the servers' answer.

```
{
"data": {
    "getCityByName": {
        "id": "112931",
        "name": "Tehran",
        "country": "IR",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 51.4215,
            "lat": 35.6944
        }
    }
}
```

To give a model answer, I should have a model like this:

```
data class CityModel(
    val data: Data
)

data class Data(
    val getCityByName: GetCityByName
)

data class GetCityByName(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val country: String,
    val coord: Coord
)

data class Coord(
    val lon: Double,
    val lat: Double
)
```

And these two changes:

```
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                cityModel = response.body()}
```

and

```
suspend fun postDynamicQuery(@Body body: String): Response<CityModel>
```

PROBLEM: I want a city model without creating a Data model and a CityModel model. this is a boilerplate to make two extra models for each API.

- I used GsonConverterFactory for converting to model:

  ```
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for solving this problem. The only way is using the Appolo library.
It has some benefits that I'll mention.

1. Type-safety: All models are created automatically by the schema. Also, you can use the models in your application.
2. Less-code: this library provides some code via using the GraphQL schematic.
3. Error-free: your queries and model are created automatically by the schematic, and as a result, you don't have any mistakes.
4. Some tools provided for you IDE for easy using
   [image: GraphQL tools]

For adding this library you need to add these dependencies on your build.gradle file.

```
    implementation("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.3.2")
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
```